# Is there anything to read from the "shadows" out in the world map?

Tags: tales-of-symphonia-hd

While out on the world map i have noticed that there are 2 types of "shadow" for enemies i can encounter, blobs and what looks to be tadpoles with legs. i have also noticed 4 behaviors with them

- Stationary
- Wandering
- Jumping Up and Down
- Running Towards Me

The last one i assume is supposed to be a way to force me into a fight on occasion so i don't just traverse the world map avoiding enemies all the time.

But is there anything to read from these "shadows" and their behavior that might better prepare me for the ensuring battle?

Answer (score 3):

No, the enemies that are represented by the shadows are static according to **the time of day** and **where you are on the map**.

The ones that jump up and down will eventually run at you - these shadows just give you an extra challenge in trying to escape from them. They have no bearing on which enemies you will encounter once you fight them.

The bigger shadows DO matter, those indicate the stronger enemies in the area (stronger meaning more or the higher level enemies of the area). The behavior of them can be the same of the smaller ones though.